# Not able to append to file with java?

Tags: java, file, append

I am currently trying to add the string "testing" to inventory.txt just to see if my file is being appended successfully. For some reason, it won't append! It compiles and runs successfully, but "testing" never shows up in my file. I did a bunch of googling online and I think I'm doing it right.... can someone try and help me find my error? THanks!

```
/**
Add in javadoc comments
*/


//import statements
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Try { 
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //variables
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean valid = false;
        int mainSelect = 0;
        int itemOption = 0;
        boolean valid2 = false;
        boolean returnToMain = false;
        String theName = "";
        double thePrice = 0;
        int theQuantity = 0;
        double currBal;
        String lampName;
        double lampPrice;
        int lampQuantity;
        String chairName;
        double chairPrice;
        int chairQuantity;
        String deskName;
        double deskPrice;
        int deskQuantity;
        int sellAmnt;
        boolean valid3 = false;

        //create file
        try{
            PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("inventory.txt");
            outputFile.println("3000.0");
            outputFile.println("Lamps 15.3 400");
            outputFile.println("Chairs 19.95 250");
            outputFile.println("Desks 95.0 300");
            outputFile.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("File cannot be created.");
        }

        //read data in from file
        try{
            File file = new File("inventory.txt");
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);
            currBal = inFile.nextDouble();
            lampName = inFile.next();
            lampPrice = inFile.nextDouble();
            lampQuantity = inFile.nextInt();
            chairName = inFile.next();
            chairPrice = inFile.nextDouble();
            chairQuantity = inFile.nextInt();
            deskName = inFile.next();
            deskPrice = inFile.nextDouble();
            deskQuantity = inFile.nextInt();
            inFile.close();

            //present user with main menu
            do{
            System.out.println("Current Balance: $" + currBal);
            System.out.println("\t1. " + lampName  + "\t\t(" + lampQuantity +  " at $" + lampPrice + ")");
            System.out.println("\t2. " + chairName + "\t\t(" + chairQuantity +  " at $" + chairPrice + ")");
            System.out.println("\t3. " + deskName + "\t\t(" + deskQuantity +  " at $" + deskPrice + ")");
            System.out.println("\t0. Exit");

            while(valid == false){
                System.out.print("\nPlease enter choice: ");
                try{
                    mainSelect = kb.nextInt();
                    if(0 <= mainSelect || mainSelect >=  3){
                        valid = true;
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("That is not a valid selection. Try again.");
                    }
                }
                catch(InputMismatchException ime){
                    System.out.println("That is not a valid selection. Try again.");
                    kb.next();
                }
            }
            //present user with second menu
            switch(mainSelect){
                case 1:
                    theQuantity = lampQuantity;
                    thePrice = lampPrice;
                    theName = lampName;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    theQuantity = chairQuantity;
                    thePrice = chairPrice;
                    theName = chairName;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    theQuantity = deskQuantity;
                    thePrice = deskPrice;
                    theName = deskName;
                    break;
                case 0:
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println("\nCurrent balance: $" + currBal);
            System.out.println("Current Quantity: " + theQuantity);
            System.out.println("Current price: $" + thePrice);
            System.out.println("1. Sell " + theName);
            System.out.println("2. Buy " + theName);
            System.out.println("3. Change price");
            System.out.println("0. Return to main menu");

            while(valid2 == false){
                System.out.print("\nPlease enter choice: ");
                try{
                    itemOption = kb.nextInt();
                    if(0 <= itemOption || itemOption >=  3){
                        valid2 = true;
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("That is not a valid selection. Try again.");
                    }
                }
                catch(InputMismatchException ime){
                    System.out.println("That is not a valid selection. Try again.");
                    kb.next();
                }
            }
            //Action: sell
            if(itemOption == 1){
                do{
                    System.out.print("Amount to sell (current quantity: " + theQuantity + "): ");
                    sellAmnt = kb.nextInt();
                    returnToMain = true;
                    try{
                        sellAmnt = kb.nextInt();
                        if(0 <= sellAmnt ||  sellAmnt >= theQuantity){
                            valid3 = true;
                            try{
                                //append file
                                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("inventory.txt", true);
                                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
                                pw.write("testing"); //not working!!!!!!!!!!
                                pw.close();
                            }
                            catch(IOException e){
                                System.out.println("File not found.");
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            System.out.println("\nThat amount is not within quantity bounds. Please enter a number within bounds.");
                        }
                    }
                    catch(InputMismatchException ime){
                        System.out.println("That is not a valid number. Try again.");
                        kb.next();
                    }
                }while(valid3 == false);
            }
            //Action: buy
            if(itemOption == 2){
                returnToMain = true;
            }
            //Action: change price
            if(itemOption == 3){
                returnToMain = true;
            }

            }while(returnToMain == true);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Cannot find file.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Too much code, just show us that part(s) most relevant to your issue

Comment: Is your code for appending being executed? I can see there are couple of if condition before that.

Comment: Please follow the recommendations of other commenters and a) provide a minimal piece of code that will reproduce the failure. Chances are you will solve your issue in the process and b) verify the conditions you have for entering block where "testing"  should be written. Add some logs to check that your code reaches that, or use a debugger to follow the execution.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
//create file
try{
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("inventory.txt");
    outputFile.println("3000.0");
    outputFile.println("Lamps 15.3 400");
    outputFile.println("Chairs 19.95 250");
    outputFile.println("Desks 95.0 300");
    outputFile.close();
}
catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println("File cannot be created.");
}
```

You're always recreating the file and adding content to it, then saving it. No matter what you do with the file, it will be rewritten every time you execute your application.

As a recommendation, this piece of code should be executed only if your file doesn't exist.

Comment: This does not seem accurate, as he is creating `FileWriter` with `append` paramter set to `true`.

Comment: @h7r even if you use the `boolean` parameter in the constructor of `PrintWriter` to append the content, I can't find a reason to keep adding this info in case the base file doesn't exist. For future usages of this file, then yes, it should be opened by using `new PrintWriter("inventory.txt", true);`.

Comment: Might be, but a) his question is not about style or good practices b) as I said, it's the `FileWriter` that is being opened as such. `PrintWriter`  does not have an `append` flag, but an `autoFlush`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.Writer,%20boolean%29

Comment: @h7r you're right on b) but not on a). And this should solve the problem.

Comment: you are basing this on your interpretation and not on what was asked. And this will probably not solve the issue until the fact that the code is probably never reaching the writing block is cleared out.

Comment: @h7r I just wrote a class and threw this code and the code in `try { FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("inventory.txt", true);` ... and the generated file included `"testing"` in the end. Probably OP's code is not entering there due to this condition: `if(0 <= sellAmnt ||  sellAmnt >= theQuantity){` and that can be tested by using a debugger. I still stand with this post as an answer.